# Select Query: Displaying a Row in Given No of Times

Tags: sql

How can i write a Select statement that selects say `Code=A-101` no of times.
If 5, select them 5 times like:

SlNo       Code

1           A-101

2 A-101

3 A-101

4 A-101

5 A-101

Comment: Which one 5 rows must output? what is criteria? also tag your database

Comment: Looks to me like you're displaying 5 distinct rows, not the same row 5 times.  But, depending on your version of SQL, it seems that `SELECT TOP` or `LIMIT` will do the trick.

Comment: Add some sample table data and its expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Specify your database - there are no good universal SQL solutions for that.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: There is no quantity column in your example. Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question and some sample data as `insert` statements and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Numbers table (which is just a table containing sequential integers).  Then you can join your data table to the Numbers table.  Here's an example in SQL Server:

```
--Create Numbers table
CREATE TABLE Numbers (Number INT NOT NULL);
DECLARE @i INT;
SELECT @i = 1;

WHILE @i <= 10000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers(Number) VALUES (@i);
    SELECT @i = @i + 1;
END;

--Create test data table
create table Test(Code varchar(10));
insert Test
select 'A-101' union
select 'A-102' union
select 'A-103' union
select 'A-104' union
select 'A-105'

--Display rows 5 times
declare @numTimes int = 5

select t.Code
from Test t
join Numbers n on n.Number <= @numTimes
where t.Code = 'A-101'
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/JRKYNY56106)